# Peculiar result of InverseHankelTransform

Tags: inverse, integral-transforms

In using the HankelTransform and its inverse I find that the inverse does not lead to the initial input. I begin with r (the independent variable) in the denominator but end up with r0 (a constant) in the denominator. Can anyone explain this?

```
ringDelta = 1/(2 π r) DiracDelta[r - r0];

fRingDelta = HankelTransform[ringDelta, r, ρ]

(* (BesselJ[0,r0 ρ] HeavisideTheta[r0])/(2 π) *)

InverseHankelTransform[fRingDelta, ρ, r]

(* (DiracDelta[r-r0] HeavisideTheta[r0])/(2 π r0) *)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmmm. I am not 100 % sure because I am not familiar with Hankel transforms. But I read in the docs that `HankelTransform` implicitly assumes that the input function is supported in $]0,\infty[$. So, if `ringDelta` is nonzero, `r0` has to be positive. As I said, this is implicitly assumed; for the return value of `InverseHankelTransform`, this is stated explicitly by multiplying with `HeavisideTheta[r0]`. Moreover, notice that
`1/(2 π r) DiracDelta[r - r0]` equals `1/(2 π r0) DiracDelta[r - r0]`.

We can check that the result of `InverseHankelTransform` equals `ringDelta` in the distributional sense by integrating against a symbolic test function:

```
Integrate[(ringDelta - InverseHankelTransform[fRingDelta, ρ, r]) ϕ[r], 
 {r, 0, ∞}, 
 Assumptions -> r0 > 0
 ]
```

> 0

Comment: I think your explanation is entirely correct.

Comment: Thank you, Henrik. I was so surprised by the inverse looking different that I did not notice the equality.

Comment: You're welcome, David. I guess these integral transforms and `DiracDelta`s hide enough surprises for all of us.